# How to set first row to 1, than 2 and so on

Tags: sql

i got a dataset and a ID-Number ( not starting from 1, they are mixed).

I want to add a new column and give the first row the "NewID" = 1, the next than 2 and so on.

Example

```
ID  Name  Bus
232  XY    VT
676  NT    OP
```

Need this:

```
ID  Name  Bus  NewID
232  XY    VT    1
676  NT    OP    2
```

and so on

Comment: you need to tell us what platform you are on -- mysql is different than db2 for example.

Comment: Learn how to ask question and give complete information.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The most important information you can give is which dbms you are using.  It's useless if someone give you a solution, but you can't use it because it's for the wrong dbms.  The answer below will work if you happen to use `SQL Server`.  Otherwise it's a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: @Eric: Hogan's answer is actually standard SQL which will work with any modern DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not every dbms has `OVER` clause.

Comment: @Eric: there are way more DBMS supporting window functions than there are not supporting them. Even MySQL has arrived in the 21st century

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your platform and your actual SQL (which you did not post) but the following will probably work.

```
select ID, Name, Bus, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS NewID
from a_table_name_you_did_not_tell_us
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to set up the ID_New column as an identity column. As you already have it then we can create a new column, drop the id_new column and then rename new column to id_new.

```
Alter Table Names Add Id_new1 Int Identity(1,1)
Go

Alter Table Names Drop Column ID_New
Go

Exec sp_rename 'Names.Id_new1', 'ID_new','Column'
```

Comment: Wow, so you think they are using SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

This how you can do this in mysql

```
SET @pos := 0;
UPDATE table_name SET new_id = ( SELECT @pos := @pos + 1 ) order by old_id;
```